# $resource always returning page 1 of paginated data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

**Problem**
When requesting page 2 of 3 pages of paginated HAL json from my RESTful interface (Apigility), results for page 1 are always returned.

I have a RESTful api on my server which returns HAL json to an angularjs single page application (SPA).

On a page I have implemented angular-ui bootstrap paginator. Here's the relevant code;

```
<pagination direction-links="false" boundary-links="true" total-items="FooCtrl.totalItems" items-per-page="Footrl.itemsPerPage" ng-model="Foo.currentPage" ng-change="Foo.changePage()"></pagination>
```

The SPA communicates with a controller which looks like;

```
angular.module('FooApp')
.controller('FooCtrl', ['$scope', 'FooApi', function($scope, FooApi) {

    var self                    = this;

    // Holds HalJson for use in pagination
    var halJson                 = {};
    self.currentPage;
    self.numPages;
    self.totalItems;
    self.itemsPerPage           = 25;


    // List of pools that have already been created
    self.foos                   = [];
    getData();


    self.changePage             = function() {

        getData();

    }



    function getData() {

        return FooApi.query({"pageNumber": self.currentPage}).$promise
            .then(function(_json) {

                processJson(_json);

            });

    }



    function processJson(halJson) {

        self.foos               = halJson._embedded.foos;
        self.currentPage        = halJson.page;
        self.numPages           = halJson.page_count;
        self.totalItems         = halJson.total_items;

    }


}]);
```

The controller requests data from service which looks like;

```
angular.module('FooApp')
.factory('FooApi', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    var self                    = this;
    var url                     =  "www.someurl/foo/:foo_id";

    return $resource( url,{"foo_id":"@foo_id"},
    {
        'query':{
            method:     'GET',
            isArray:    false,
        },
        'update':{
            method:     'PATCH',
            isArray:    false,
        }
    });

}]);
```

I have tried hitting page 2 manually via postman and it returns the expected results.

I have echoed out *currentPage* variable in the getData() function of the controller, just before making a server request and it is definitely set to 2.

Any ideas?

Comment: $resource param doesn't match param passed to query. Look at the actual url used in dev tools network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://apigility.org/documentation/api-primer/halprimer (section on Collections) HAL JSON expects a "page=" parameter.

In the getData function of your controller you seem to be passing in "pageNumber=" in the paramdefaults JSON.  Perhaps this is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Ah that's embarrassing. You are absolutely right, Many thanks!